# I need help determining what's changing my data in my own filter method

Tags: c++, data-analysis, root-framework

I'm currently doing some data analysis in C++ / ROOT, and ran into a problem with impossible data. I've narrowed it down to the method below, which is supposed to impose a filter on the data, but somehow also changes it. I've also inserted some counters (the two blocks with the integer k), which tells me that my data actually changes. As far as I can see, however, it only copies from the input, and should not be able to create new values.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
vector<int> debug_dt_filter(double a, double b, const vector<double> *DT, const vector<int> *input, const vector<int> *ID) {
    int n = DT->size();
    const vector<double> &DTref = *DT;
    const vector<int> &inputref = *input;
    vector<int> result(n);
    int m = 0; // current index in result
    double dt;

    int k = 0;
    const vector<int> &id = *ID;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputref.size(); i++) {
        if (inputref[i] > 24 && (id[i] == 2 || id[i] == 3)) {
            k++;
        }
    }
    cout << "k: " << k << endl; // prints k = 0

    // this is where the data is changed
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dt = DTref[i];
        if (a < dt && dt < b) {
            result[m] = inputref[i];
            m++;
        }
    }

    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        if (result[i] > 24 && (id[i] == 2 || id[i] == 3)) {
            k++;
        }
    }
    cout << "k: " << k << endl; // prints k = 9

    result.resize(m);
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: `result[m] = inputref[i];` when `result` contains `m` members will not necessarily add a new element to `result`.  It will cause undefined behavior. You're looking for `push_back`.

Comment: I initialize `result` with size `n` and then resize it to `m` at the very end. Since `n` is the size of the input, there should be space for everything. I don't see why my approach shouldn't work?

Comment: You're right. I think the actual issue is that `id[i]` means a different thing in the second loop. In the first loop, `i` is the index in the `inputref` container. In the second loop, `i` is the index in the `result` container, which we can expect to be smaller.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. By fixing this they both print out k = 0. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan pointed out in his comment that my result and id vectors are no longer aligned after the actual filter loop. By performing the same changes in the id vector, both k statements correctly print out k = 0.